# facebook APP api notifications to all user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I can send a notification to all user that access my APP, using userid stored in a table "fbuid", and all works fine.

But if an user remove my APP the code fail and nobody get notification. How can I solve this problem.

```
$app_id = 'AAAAAAAA';
$app_secret = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
$app_access_token = $app_id . '|' . $app_secret;
$query = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM fbuid;");
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($query)) 
{
     $response = $facebook->api( '/'.$row[1].'/notifications', 'POST', array(
         'template' => 'Nuovo Annuncio Pubblicato FaiceBuy',
         'access_token' => $app_access_token
     )); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the code skips due to exception thrown after failing in 1 case. So, you should write your code in **try-catch** block, just like this-.

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($query)) 
{
     try
     {
           $response = $facebook->api( '/'.$row[1].'/notifications', 'POST', array(
               'template' => 'Nuovo Annuncio Pubblicato FaiceBuy',
               'access_token' => $app_access_token
           ));
           echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $response ['id'] . '</pre>';
     } 
     catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
     {
         echo $e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

Comment: Great this worked like a charm now i can done my APP thank you